# eBay API ReviseItem call returns 'Postage service is not available' exception

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am having troubles with updating the `ShippingDetails` using the `ReviseItem` eBay API call. As mentioned in the docs, I am first calling `GetItem` and using the same details but I keep getting the following `ApiException`

> Postage service Standard International Flat Rate Postage(51507) is not
>   available.

How do I preserve all existing shipping details apart from the `ExcludeShipToLocation` property I'm trying to update?

```
ReviseItemCall apiCall = new ReviseItemCall(Context);
GetItemCall getItemApiCall = new GetItemCall(Context);

foreach (ItemType item in items)
{
    getItemApiCall.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);
    ItemType fetchedItem = getItemApiCall.GetItem(item.ItemID);
    ShippingDetailsType shippingDetails = fetchedItem.ShippingDetails;
    shippingDetails.ExcludeShipToLocation = excludeShipToLocations;
    item.ShippingDetails = shippingDetails;

    try
    {
        apiCall.ReviseItem(item, deletedFields, false);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);        
    }
}
```